# Facing problem in making my navigation fixed

Tags: html, css, layout

[Link to the Code][1]

```
[1]: https://codepen.io/muhammad-shahzeb-raza/pen/mdRbXqX?editors=1100
```

I am trying to make my navigation stay at one point during the scroll using Position = fixed but it does not work.

Comment: I'm quite sure you got an error saying "Links to codepen.io must be accompanied by code". Why didn't you do what it says?

Answer (score 0):

This will most likely be down to your HTML structure. Consider moving the the navigation HTML outside of your wrapper. For example:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}

.menu {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height:40px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border-bottom:1px solid #d9d9d9;
  position:fixed;
  background:white;
}

.content {
  width:100%;
  height:3000px;
  background:#f1f1f1;
  margin-top:40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu"> Menu </div>
<div class="content"> Content </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move .header__nav just above your #section-header, and make sure it has position: fixed and z-index bigger than 3, like this: https://codepen.io/cmarius/pen/JjEPZQy

```
&__nav{
    z-index: 4;
    border-bottom: .1rem solid $color-light;
    position: fixed;
}
```

However, it's worth mentioning you header element should only contain header data.